# rails - how can I receive data like 'name="temp[10]"' in controller by params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I define `input name="temp[10]"`, How can I receive this input in controller?
Use params[]

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="100" name="temp[10]"></input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `params['temp']['10']`, it should do the trick.

Rails converts parameters with `[]` brackets into hashes. So your controller receives something like `"temp"=>{"10"=>"100"}`.

Such input:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="100" name="temp[10]"></input>
<input type="checkbox" value="value for 20" name="temp[20]"></input>
<input type="checkbox" value="value for 30" name="temp[30]"></input>
```

Will result in the following controller parameters (if everything was checked):

```
"temp"=>{"10"=>"100", "20"=>"value for 20", "30"=>"value for 30"}
```

So accessing it:

```
params['temp']['10'] # holds "100"
params['temp']['20'] # holds "value for 20"
```

Comment: NUMBER in temp[NUMBER] will often be changed. Then, what should I do? I want a solution which can recieve all of NUMBER...

Comment: I've updated the answer, you will receive all those numbers in a hash.

Comment: So do I need params['temp']['10']['20']['30']['....  in controller? There are many NUMBERs. and For example, temp[10] can be checked / un-checked. Then How can I recieve that?

Comment: No, to get the individual values use: `params['temp']['10']`, `params['temp']['20']`, `params['temp']['30']`. And to get all the values as an array use: `params['temp'].values`

Answer (score 0):

The `params` object is a *hash*, which means that any params you pass to your controller will be assigned a key.

Your code *should* use [Rails' helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag):

```
<%= check_box_tag "temp[10]", "100" %>
```

As mentioned in the other answer, this will create the params hash:

```
params: {
   temp: {
     10: "100",
      x: "y"
   }
}
```

.. which you can access with `params[:temp][:10]`, or:

```
params[:temp].each do |k,v|
   puts "#{k}:#{v}"
end
```

... or ...

```
def temp_params
   params.require(:temp).permit(:10, :20, :30)
end
```

Comment: btw, at least as of ruby 2.2.3, things like `:10` generate a syntax error, so you should probably just use the string instead  `'10'`.